# For superadmin user: flag (IsSuperAdmin) o role?

Tags: symfony, laravel, cakephp, permissions, roles

I'm modeling a permission strategy for a site.
I have this type of user:

- Superadmin: the initial user and he can create others admins
- Admin
- Customer

For Admin and Customer i used a role assignment. But for SuperAdmin i don't know if i should use a role or a simple flag (boolean "IsSuperAdmin")
What is your opinion? thanks.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow as answers will be based on opinion rather than fact. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Two choices = boolean. Three = list of roles. Easy enough?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja okk. Just I came to ask that, if there is a right way or at least a convention. Sorry for the troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is you can create a new table `user_roles` for adding roles.

Fields,

```
id    role_name
```

Then create a field `user_role_id` in your users table for storing the role id.

We can check the roles in session to access their methods.